# how to tell the default target (all:) to execute this target :$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o:

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This is the makefile I've "invented"

```
CFLAGS = gcc -Isourcfiles
EXE_DIR = ../bin/exefile
OBJECT_DIR = objectfiles

SOURCEFILES = $(wildcard sourcefiles/*.c *.c)

all: $(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o
        gcc -o $(EXEFILE) $<

$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEFILES)
        $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

The problem is that the target `$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o` have never been executed.
Some advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making several mistakes. (You ought to have started with something simpler.)

This:

```
all: $(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o
    gcc -o $(EXEFILE) $<
```

is not a pattern rule, and the "%" is not a wildcard. This rule has one prerequisite, a file named `objectfiles/%.o`, which is probably not what you intended. And you haven't told us how you define `EXEFILE` (if you do), and it probably isn't "all", so this rule doesn't actually build a file whose name is the target of the rule, which can cause problems.

This:

```
$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEFILES)
    $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

*is* a pattern rule, but it makes *all* source files prerequisites of *every* object file. Then it uses only the first of those files (`aardvark.c` or something) to build the desired object, no matter what the desired object is. Then it puts the object file in the current directory, not `objectfiles`. And putting `gcc` in `CFLAGS` is highly misleading.

First, let's make pattern rules for objects:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Isourcfiles

$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o: sourcefiles/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

(We need two rules because the source files are in two different places-- this is not the most elegant solution, but it is the simplest.) **Do not proceed until you understand these rules.**

Now for the executable, we need a list of object files. Suppose your source files are `red.c`, `blue.c` and `sourcefiles/green.c`.

```
SOURCEFILES = $(wildcard sourcefiles/*.c *.c)
# This is red.c blue.c sourcefiles/green.c

SOURCENAMES = $(notdir $(SOURCEFILES))
# This is red.c blue.c green.c

OBJECTNAMES = $(SOURCENAMES:.c=.o)
# This is red.o blue.o green.o

OBJECTFILES = $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIR)/, $(OBJECTNAMES))
# This is objectfiles/red.o objectfiles/blue.o objectfiles/green.o
```

Now we can write the rule for the executable:

```
$(EXEFILE): $(OBJECTFILES)
    gcc -o $@ $^
```

Further refinements are possible, once you have this working.

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable information. One more thing to clarify pleas. If % is not a wildcard then what is it. Why in some cases we use for example *.c and in others %.c? Whats the difference and what convention says when we use % and when *?

Comment: In a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules), the "%" in the target is a wildcard that can match portions of a desired target, and any "%" characters in the prerequisite list are assigned the same string that matched the "%" in the target. (If a rule does not have a "%" in the target, then it is not a pattern rule; your `all` rule is not a pattern rule, therefore the "%" in the prerequisite is just a character.)  The [`wildcard` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function) uses "*" as a wildcard. They are not the same.